# What is the error in this proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Note:** This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications `[7th ed, prob 49, page 583]`.

[image]

This proof seems legit to me.
If you know R is transitive, you know if (a,b)$\in$R,  (b,c)$\in$R, then (a,c)$\in$R,
If you know R is symmetric, you know  if (a,b)$\in$R, then (b,a)$\in$R 
Just replace the 'c' in transitive with 'a' and you have (a,b)$\in$R,  (b,a)$\in$R, then (a,a)$\in$R
Does anyone see any issues with this proof?

Comment: There may be no element $b$ for which $(a,b)\in R$.

Comment: huh? that's like saying if x is positive, x > 0. And there may be no element for which x is positive, so this statement is flawed?

Comment: It's more like trying to proof that $\mathbb{R}^+$ has negative elements by saying 'take an $x<0$, this is negative'. Well that doesn't work, since there is no such $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: If $R = \{(1,2),(2,1), (1,1), (2,2)\}$ is a relation on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$, then $R$ is indeed symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive: $(3, 3) \not\in R$.

Comment: @SteveKass is right, and if I may elaborate: For your relation $R$ to be reflexive, you need that $(a,a)\in R$ for *all* $a\in A$. But not every element $a\in A$ need to be related to other elements via $R$. So when you take an element $a\in A$, and take an element $b\in A$ for which $(a,b)\in R$, this $b$ need not exist: The chosen element $a$ might not be related to anything.

Comment: The fact that $R$ is symmetric means that **if** $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)\in R$. The **if** is important. Just because something happens **if** something else doesn’t mean the “something else” ever happens. If I am standing behind you, then you are in front of me. True, no? Am I standing behind you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty relation on a non-empty set is symmetric and transitive. It is not reflexive. The theorem is thus false.

The bit of the proof that you looked at is indeed fine. Yes, if $R$ is transitive and reflexive and there is some pair $(a,b)\in R$, then, as you follow, $(b,a)\in R$ and thus $(a,a)\in R$. However, *before* that step, the proof assumes that, for any $a$, you can pick some $b$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ which is not necessarily true, like in the empty relation. A more accurate statement would be:

> If $R$ is a relation on $A$ that is symmetric and transitive and has that $\forall a\in A\exists b\in A[(a,b)\in R]$, then it is reflexive.

or, to be tighter, but less elegant:

> If $R$ is a relation on $A$ that is symmetric and transitive relation and $a\in A$, then $\exists b\in A[(a,b)\in R]$ implies $(a,a)\in R$.