# Can a relation from A to some other set B also be considered symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, equivalence-relations

**Note:** This definition is from Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications `[7th ed,  page 577]`.

[image]

This is my book's definition of a relation R on a set A
[image]

My question is does the definition of a symmetric relation extend to a relation from a set A to another set B, that doesn't have to be A?
Say you have two sets, A {1,2} and set B {1,2,3}
Suppose a relation R from the set A to the set B is the empty set, {} (legit relation because the empty set is a subset of A x B)
From what I learned here  [Symmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169432/what-is-the-error-in-this-proof), the empty relation is technically symmetric because there are no elements (a,b) to violate the symmetric definition. Now would this relation symmetric even if it isn't a relation from A to A?

Comment: A subset $R$ of $A\times B$ is a relation (from $A$ to $B$). Relations can be labeled as symmetric only if $A=B$. So if $A\neq B$ then relation $\varnothing\subseteq A\times B$ will not get that label. Actually a relation must be looked at as a triple $\langle A,R,B\rangle$ with $R\subseteq A\times B$. In that sense you can say: no if $A\neq B$ then relation $\langle A,\varnothing, B\rangle$ is not symmetric, but yes relation $\langle A,\varnothing,A\rangle$ is symmetric.

Comment: A triple ordered pair of sets? I didn't get that.

Comment: If the question rises: is relation $R$ symmetric? Then an answer can only be given if it is known what the domain of $R$ is (in my former comment set $A$) and what the codomain of $R$ is (in my former comment set $B$). So $R$ on itself does not give all data. That leads to the triple I mentioned. Don't take it too heavy yet. Keep looking at relations as subsets of products $A\times B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the word "symmetric" is only used about relations from a set to itself. If the relation is from a set to a different set, we don't call it symmetric -- not because it fails to satisfy the condition, but because the question "is it symmetric or not?" is not supposed to be asked about relations between different sets in the first place.

However, if you want to use the word about relations from $A$ to $B$ that happen to satisfy the formal condition, nobody's stopping you. But the burden will be on you to make sure that you're not being misunderstood when you do so (some readers may think you're implicitly saying that the relation is from $A$ to $A$ when you call it "symmetric"), and also to avoid using results that are formulated as *"Let $R$ be a symmetric relation. Then such-and-such."* which actually hold only when $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $A$, as is commonly implied.

Comment: What's so special about a relation from a set to itself? I tried doing a Google search but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @committedandroider partial orders and equivalence relations are examples of relations from a set to itself. Very special and important stuff.

Comment: @drhab Thanks stuff to look forward to :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we had such a symmetric relation between A and B.  Then, for each element $a\in A$ so that $a\,R\,b$ for $b\in B$, it follows that $b\,R\,a$.  Hence, $b\in A$ and $a\in B$.  This means that $a,b\in A\cap B$ for $a,b$.  Thus, this relation could really just be considered a symmetric relation on $A\cap B$.  So even if you have defined such a symmetric relation between two sets, it's really just a symmetric relation on a single set.

Comment: Whats the difference between $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,R\,a$ ?

Comment: $a\,R\,b$ means that the element $a$ in $A$ relates to the element $b$ in $B$.  $b\,R\,a$ means that the element $b$ in $A$ relates to the element $a$ in $B$.

Comment: So $a\,R\,b$ is the same thing as saying (a, b) in order pair notation?

Comment: ah. Yes, sorry, different notation.

Comment: Shouldn't "it follows that $b\,R\,A$"  be "it follows that $b\,R\,a$"?

Comment: Yes. Yes it should be

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. I followed your argument to "it follows that $b\,R\,a$". However this part - "hence, $b\in A$ and $a\in B$". Your conclusion was that b is related to a but would you know that b is in set A?

Comment: Because a relation from $A$ to $B$ is defined as $(a,b)\in R$ if $a\in A$ relates to $b\in B$.  Basically, the first element always corresponds to the first set, the second element to the second set.